# How to parse input string in standard ISO 8601 format in UTC to Java?

Tags: java-8

The following java code throws an exception

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

simpleDateFormat.parse("2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z") 


java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

any idea how can i fix this issue

Comment: To other folks: I know this Question is a duplicate. But when I tried to find a close original, I discovered that is surprisingly difficult. So perhaps this Question can be the original for the inevitable duplicates in the future. I changed the title to be easy to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z" )
```

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later, with a [back-port for Java 6 & 7](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

You are using their terrible predecessor classes, bundled with the earliest versions of Java. The `SimpleDateFormat` class and its siblings are flawed,  developed by people who did not understand date-time handling. Avoid these classes entirely.

## ISO 8601

Your input string represents a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end is short for UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

For a moment in UTC, use the class [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z" ) ;
```

To see this same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, apply a `ZoneId` (time zone) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UebXWk).

> instant.toString(): 2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2019-09-10T03:06:26.287-04:00[America/Montreal]

Same moment, same simultaneous point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [dateparser](https://github.com/sisyphsu/dateparser).

It can recognize any **String** automatically, and parse it into **Date**, **Calendar**, **LocalDateTime**, **OffsetDateTime** correctly.

With it, you don't have to prepare any appropriate patterns like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`:

```java
Date date = DateParserUtils.parseDate("2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z");
Calendar calendar = DateParserUtils.parseCalendar("2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z");
LocalDateTime dateTime = DateParserUtils.parseDateTime("2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z");
```

Please enjoy it.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the **wrong class** for that input string. You are discarding valuable offset information.

Comment: `2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z` has the offset `+00:00`, it could be parsed as `OffsetDateTime`, but `OffsetDateTime` could be converted to be `LocalDateTime`, it is **correct**. For example, if your local zone is `+02:00`, `2019-09-10T07:06:26.287Z` could be parsed as `2019-09-10 09:06:26.287`